# convert localtime to utc time in perl

Tags: perl, datetime

I calculated time that is 10 minutes before current time. i need to convert it into UTC time using perl script. Please help.
I have used this code :-

```
my $dt = time();
$dt = $dt - 10 * 60;   # 10 minutes before of current date.
```

I want time in this format :-

2014-08-14T05:52:16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider using `strftime`, available via the POSIX module. See:

```
perldoc POSIX
```

for information on the module, and

```
man strftime
```

for information on the function. You could use it as e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $dt = time();
$dt -= 10 * 60;

print "Datetime: ", strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.', gmtime($dt)), "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

[Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) gives a slightly higher level interface to things like strftime.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

my $now = gmtime;
$now -= 10*60;
say $now->strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S');
```